# Spring MVC not working in intellij idea 10

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij IDEA  10.5, Tomcat 7.0.34, and spring framework version 3.0.5 with spring MVC, I've added the spring mvc with maven dependencies and I can see it in my class path for external libraries, and auto complete is working and everything is Good up till the moment I Run in tomcat I get this error in debug mode:-

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

I tried adding the libraries directly in Tomcat's lib folder and removing the dependancy, but then it misses things up even more. Giving the error:-

> org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Class
>   [org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler] for
>   namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context] does not
>   implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler]
>   interface

I saw people saying that this is because Spring libs are not deployed to Tomcat, BUT how can include them? how to get this running correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours and hours of pointless search on the internet and much much googling, I finally figured out what was wrong, Seems that intellij IDEA does not include spring maven libraries, and more libraries not just spring, to solve this do the following:

1. Open IDEA's module settings.
2. Click on your module and open the output layout tab.
3. open the root directory and go to the lib directory.
4. Click on the + icon and then library files and select your files from the Project Library.

This is how it worked for me, if you see an error like this with tomcat first make sure your classes are in your output war this way.

Comment: Be aware that your manual dependencies will be dropped as soon as you reimport from Maven again. IDEA should import all the dependencies defined in POM automatically, but you may use some feature or Maven version that is not supported by 3-years old IDE version. IDEA 12.1 will probably work better.

Comment: @CrazyCoder yes I know IDEa 12.1 is much much better, but the company here is using pretty old stuff :S (Spring 3.0.5 Hibernate 3.5) along with this old IDE so I'm forced to do so